# Delete all stored procedures in a specific SQL Server schema

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have hundreds of procedures auto generated by DataSync.

I don't have the time and sense to delete them manually.

They all start with `DataSync.`

Is there a way to delete all stored procedures where the name start with `DataSync.`?

Comment: Which RDBMS would this be in?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the information_schema.routines (which is fairly standard across RDBMSs such as MSSQL,Mysql):

If your proc names start "DataSync." then they are probably in a schema, so you can find them with:

```
select
    'DROP PROCEDURE [' + routine_schema + '].[' + routine_name + ']'
from 
    information_schema.routines where routine_schema = 'DataSync' and routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

If your proc names start "DataSync" then you can find them with:

```
select
    'DROP PROCEDURE [' + routine_schema + '].[' + routine_name + ']'
from 
    information_schema.routines where routine_name like 'DataSync%' and routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

If you wanted to execute all these drop statements, you can build a single execute using FOR XML PATH as follows:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @sql = (
select
    'DROP PROCEDURE [' + routine_schema + '].[' + routine_name + '] ' 
from 
    information_schema.routines where routine_schema = 'DataSync' and routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
FOR XML PATH ('')
)

exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you mean **SQL Server** when you specify "SQL" - then the easiest way is this: run this query:

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    DropCmd = 'DROP PROCEDURE DataSync.' + name 
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE 
     schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('DataSync')
```

and the even "lazier" version would be to use a cursor to do this automatically for you:

```
DECLARE DropSpCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT 
        name
    FROM sys.procedures
    WHERE schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('DataSync')

DECLARE @StoredProcName sysname
DECLARE @DropStatement NVARCHAR(1000)

OPEN DropSpCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM DropSpCursor INTO @StoredProcName, @SchemaName

WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
    IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
    BEGIN
        SET @DropStatement = N'DROP PROCEDURE DataSync.' + @StoredProcName
        EXEC(@DropStatement)
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM DropSpCursor INTO @StoredProcName
END

CLOSE DropSpCursor 
DEALLOCATE DropSpCursor
```

Comment: Am wondering about the "." at the end of the name stem he said. Maybe they're all in a schema.

Comment: @JonEgerton: good point - updated my answer with an optional second way of doing this

Comment: Yeah true, they are in a schema

Comment: I fancied using STUFF,ForXML and making a single executable statement of all the drops (just for fun like!)

Comment: @JonEgerton: <hehe> seems like you have **too much time** on your hands!! :-)

Comment: @marc_s: Possibly. It is a lot shorter to code that way though - and it doesn't even need `STUFF`

Answer (score 3):

No need for XML or loops:

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = ''

select @sql += 'drop procedure [' + routine_schema + '].[' + routine_name + '];'
from information_schema.routines where routine_schema = 'DataSync' and routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'

exec(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @name  AS VARCHAR(max)

DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT name FROM sys.objects WHERE type='P' AND schema_id=SCHEMA_ID('DataSync')

OPEN MyCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC('DROP PROCEDURE DataSync.' + @name)
    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @name
END

CLOSE MyCursor
DEALLOCATE MyCursor
```

EDIT: changed where clause since it turned out DataSync is a schema name.

Comment: Since those stored procedures are inside a `DataSync` schema, this code will fail - the "name" will be something like `storedproc1` but the command `DROP PROCEDURE storedproc1` will fail, since you need to add the **schema** to that sproc name!

Comment: @marc_s: thanks for pointing (it wasn't clear in the original version of the question whether DataSync is a schema)

Comment: Two things: it's still not going to work, since the `name` that you get from the system catalog views does not contain the schema - so your command still is `DROP PROCEDURE proc1` and that won't work. Also: I would always use the most specific catalog view, e.g. `sys.procedures` - that way you don't even need to specify the type of object you want - that's obvious from the catalog view you use

Comment: Thanks, good point. The second one, well a bit more efficient but functionally no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this short script to clear all SPs from a given schema (when using SQL Server). It iterates direct sys.procedures.

```
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(100)
SET @schema = 'DataSync'

DECLARE @CurrentStatement AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @CurrentStatement = (SELECT TOP(1)  'DROP PROCEDURE [' + @schema + '].[' + name + ']'
FROM sys.procedures 
WHERE schema_id = SCHEMA_ID(@schema))

WHILE @CurrentStatement IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    EXEC (@CurrentStatement)    
    SET @CurrentStatement = (SELECT TOP(1)  'DROP PROCEDURE [' + @schema + '].[' + name + ']'
    FROM sys.procedures 
    WHERE schema_id = SCHEMA_ID(@schema))
END
```

The premise is very similar to the answer provided by marc_s; however doesn't utilize a cursor for the iteration. While there's a record in sys.procedures matching our schema, we need to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

**try this with sql2012 or above,**

this will be help to delete all objects by selected schema
keep 'P' and remove rest for stored procedure only (o.type IN ('P')

```
DECLARE @MySchemaName VARCHAR(50)='dbo', @sql VARCHAR(MAX)='';
DECLARE @SchemaName VARCHAR(255), @ObjectName VARCHAR(255), @ObjectType VARCHAR(255), @ObjectDesc VARCHAR(255), @Category INT;

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  (s.name)SchemaName, (o.name)ObjectName, (o.type)ObjectType,(o.type_desc)ObjectDesc,(so.category)Category
    FROM    sys.objects o
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sysobjects so ON so.name=o.name
    WHERE s.name = @MySchemaName
    AND so.category=0
    AND o.type IN ('P','PC','U','V','FN','IF','TF','FS','FT','PK','TT')

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @SchemaName,@ObjectName,@ObjectType,@ObjectDesc,@Category

SET @sql='';
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN    
    IF @ObjectType IN('FN', 'IF', 'TF', 'FS', 'FT') SET @sql=@sql+'Drop Function '+@MySchemaName+'.'+@ObjectName+CHAR(13)
    IF @ObjectType IN('V') SET @sql=@sql+'Drop View '+@MySchemaName+'.'+@ObjectName+CHAR(13)
    IF @ObjectType IN('P') SET @sql=@sql+'Drop Procedure '+@MySchemaName+'.'+@ObjectName+CHAR(13)
    IF @ObjectType IN('U') SET @sql=@sql+'Drop Table '+@MySchemaName+'.'+@ObjectName+CHAR(13)

    --PRINT @ObjectName + ' | ' + @ObjectType
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @SchemaName,@ObjectName,@ObjectType,@ObjectDesc,@Category
END
CLOSE cur;    
DEALLOCATE cur;
SET @sql=@sql+CASE WHEN LEN(@sql)>0 THEN 'Drop Schema '+@MySchemaName+CHAR(13) ELSE '' END
PRINT @sql
EXECUTE (@sql)
```