# Delete all Stored Procedures at once

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 200 `Stored Procedures` in my `Sql server 2008 R2` database that are automatically generated by an application. Now I want to delete them ***all*** and regenerate them because the tables have changed a lot.

[This question is very similar to my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191398/delete-all-stored-procedures-in-a-specific-sql-server-schema) but in my case all the SP's start with **sp_** and I thinks it's dangerous to use the same code since system SP's also start with ***sp_*** and I may kill them all.

Should I trust the solution in [the link above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191398/delete-all-stored-procedures-in-a-specific-sql-server-schema)? If not is there any safer solution?

Comment: but the `sp_` _that are automatically generated_ the extension is `.sys` and your created `sp_` is `.dbo` if am correct. so the hint is get all the `.dbo` extension and delete it :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If this is a one- time task, just open Object Explorer, expand your database > programmability and highlight the Stored Procedures node. Then turn on Object Explorer Details (F7 I think). On the right you should see your list, and here you can multi-select - so you can sort by name, choose all procedures that start with sp_, and delete them all with one keystroke.

If you are doing this repeatedly, then (assuming your procedures are all in the dbo schema):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'DROP PROCEDURE dbo.'
  + QUOTENAME(name) + ';
' FROM sys.procedures
WHERE name LIKE N'sp[_]%'
AND SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = N'dbo';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Being able to use a single `SELECT` plus `EXEC` instead of having to declare `CURSOR` and iterate through is really neat. I did not know that T-SQL allowed you to build up a string this way (`SELECT @sql +=`), very clever.

Comment: Was looking for a solution like this.
I do have a few tweaks to the query.

DECLARE \@sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT \@sql += N'DROP PROCEDURE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(p.[schema_id]) + '].' + QUOTENAME(p.[name]) + ';'
FROM sys.procedures p
WHERE p.is_ms_shipped = 0
  --AND SCHEMA_NAME(p.[schema_id]) IN (N'dbo')

EXEC sp_executesql \@sql;

The query is no longer hardcoded to the dbo schema.
Also i added a filter to avoid deleting system stored procedures.
There is also a criteria to limit by schema(s) though i didn't need it in my case.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- drop all user defined stored procedures

    Declare @procName varchar(500) 
    Declare cur Cursor For Select [name] From sys.objects where type = 'p' 
    Open cur 
    Fetch Next From cur Into @procName 
    While @@fetch_status = 0 
    Begin 
     Exec('drop procedure ' + @procName) 
     Fetch Next From cur Into @procName 
    End
    Close cur 
    Deallocate cur
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this [How to Drop All Stored Procedures in Your Database](http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/03/15/how-to-drop-all-stored-procedures-in-your-database/) then I tested and the `StoredProcedure` is created at outside of *Stored Procedures* folder.

```
CREATE PROC UserStoredProcedure_Sample1
 AS
       SELECT 'SQL Server rocks'
  GO

CREATE PROC UserStoredProcedure_Sample2
 AS
     SELECT 'SQL Server rocks'
 GO

 SET NOCOUNT ON

  -- to do this we have to use EXEC instead of sp_executesql
 -- sp_executesql does not accept a DROP command in the SQL String
 DECLARE @UserStoredProcedure    VARCHAR(100)
 DECLARE @Command                    VARCHAR(100)

 DECLARE UserStoredProcedureCursor CURSOR SCROLL STATIC READ_ONLY FOR
 SELECT
     SPECIFIC_NAME
 FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES

  OPEN UserStoredProcedureCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM UserStoredProcedureCursor
 INTO @UserStoredProcedure
  WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) BEGIN
        SET @Command = 'DROP PROCEDURE ' + @UserStoredProcedure

         -- display; visual check
         SELECT @Command

        -- when you are ready to execute, uncomment below
        EXEC (@Command)

        FETCH NEXT FROM UserStoredProcedureCursor
         INTO @UserStoredProcedure
  END


 CLOSE UserStoredProcedureCursor
 DEALLOCATE UserStoredProcedureCursor

   SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DeleteProcCommand NVARCHAR(500)

DECLARE Syntax_Cursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE ' + p.NAME
FROM sys.procedures p

OPEN Syntax_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM Syntax_Cursor

INTO @DeleteProcCommand

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

EXEC (@DeleteProcCommand)

FETCH NEXT FROM Syntax_Cursor
INTO @DeleteProcCommand

END

CLOSE Syntax_Cursor

DEALLOCATE Syntax_Cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @sql=@sql+'drop procedure ['+name +'];' FROM sys.objects 
WHERE type = 'p' AND  is_ms_shipped = 0

exec(@sql);
```